# Relative Path Question Running a Tomcat Server

Tags: java, eclipse, file, relative-path

So I have a file structure like below

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/322696/FolderPath.JPG

When I start the Tomcat Server, I'm trying to figure out where it's root folder begins with if I were just to start the server in the server window and access a jsp page within the jsp folder.  I need to navigate to images/banner/name.jpg (trying to make an image file).  I've set the servers context to '/projectname' (the black rectangle next to [repository]).  I've tried like:

```
File image = new File("../images/banner/name.jpg"); //If its root was the jsp I accessed
```

No dice.  Is there a method I could run to determine what the relative path should be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you asking how to get the on disk path from within tomcat?  If so you use the ServletContext.

getServletContext().getRealPath("/")

Comment: I wanted to use a relative path such as '../images/etc' instead of an absolute path like 'C:\program\etc'.  When trying to access the image.

Comment: @BZB you're right that it would be absolute, but it would be dynamically generated, so it achieves the same goal.

Comment: Well like for instance this project is on CVS so someone else trying to run this would need a relative path...which I still am unsure what that would be.

Comment: Hey thanks I got it working.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596501/absolute-to-relative-path-eclipse-jsp helped it make sense to me.